# How many window.event objects are there in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
<a href="#" id="a">a</a>
<script>
    document.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        event.a = 100;
        window.m = event;
        alert(event.a);
    });
    document.getElementById("a").attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        alert(event === window.m);
    })
</script>
```

In eariler versions of IE, when I click the document, I get undefined and then when I click the `#a` link I get false.

My question is; how many event objects are in global of IE?
And is the IE event object a mutable object?

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you are asking. What is `event`? It is undefined. What do you mean by "how many event object in global"? It is not a well-formed English sentence. What do you mean by "mutable"? All objects are mutable in JS.

Comment: sorry , i mean the value of event.a is undefined, i mean  the window.event  is unmutable, may be i have found the answer in(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(v=vs.85).aspx),and i found we can edit the event with (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536390(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In older versions of IE, `window.event` exposes information about the current event that is being processed. JavaScript is single-threaded - always has been and probably always will be (see Workers for an example of introducing multi-threaded-like behaviour) - As such, even if events are fired simultaneously (a `click` on a `submit` button would be one such example), they are resolved in order (`click` first, then `submit` since that's the default action of a click on that button).

Consequently, `window.event` will always give information about the current event whose handler you are in.

As far as I can tell, it's not a "normal" object that you can attach things to. This became a problem for drag-and-drop events, where you kind of need to be able to attach data to the event for it to work with the related future events. This is why we have the [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) system for events.

So there is only ever one `window.event`, but it's more of an interface into the event data than an actual object you can use. In that sense, it's similar to `window.external` I suppose.